# Why does the pictures align left

Tags: html, css

What part of the script make the pictures align to the left. www.edmazeka.co.za.
Here is the css. Or what css can I add to make only the pic align to the center

/* BASIC */

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    background: #27282C url(images/bg2.jpg);
}

body {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Abel;
    width:100%;
    min-width: 1255px;
    color: #d0d1d4;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

p {
    line-height: 1.75em;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

strong {
    color: #ffffff;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4 {
    font-weight: normal;
}

a {
    color: #6BA8E7;
}
```

/* MISC */

```
br.clear {
    clear: both;
}

img.align-left
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 50px 30px 0;
}
```

/* LAYOUT */

```
#bg0 {
    position: relative;

    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(images/bg0.jpg);
    z-index: 2;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #4B4C50;
}

#bg1 {
    min-width: 1255px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1090px;
    background: url(images/bg1.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    padding: 80px 0 100px 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

/* CONTENT */

```
#content {
    margin-left: 235px;
    width: 1020px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Too much CSS for 1 img

Comment: Sorry, could you PLEASE reduce your code to the relevant parts? Thanks.  We are not going to look through all that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule:

```
.thumbnail img {
display: block;
width: 221px;
border: 0;
}
```

is doing it. Remove the `display: block;`

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
img.align-left
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 50px 30px 0;
}
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.